# TypeORM connection issue with SQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, typeorm

I have SQL Server instance running on my local machine, when I am trying to connect a database from TypeORM it is throwing below error:

> originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

Here is my `ormconfig.ts` file looks like:

```
{
   "type": "mssql",
   "host": "localhost",
   "username": "",
   "password": "",
   "database": "demoDB",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

and here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
   "name": "PLHApi-Dev",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Performance Lighthouse Reborn.",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
      "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
      "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.1",
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
      "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "express": "^4.15.4",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "mssql": "^4.3.9",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
      "typeorm": "0.2.29"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
   }
}
```

when I am trying to run it is throwing an ESOCKET error,

```
originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at ConnectionError (E:\PLH_API\PLHApi-Dev\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
      at Connection.socketError (E:\PLH_API\PLHApi-Dev\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1024:30)
      at E:\PLH_API\PLHApi-Dev\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:868:25
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (E:\PLH_API\PLHApi-Dev\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:154:9)
      at Socket.onError (E:\PLH_API\PLHApi-Dev\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:170:16)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET'
```

I am also attaching the SSMS configuration window screenshot,

[image: SSMS Conf]

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I have SSMS instance running on my local machine"* You don't have an "SSMS Instance". SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is an IDE; nothing more. You have a SQL Server instance which you are connecting to *via* SSMS. Also, that image isn't of your configuration settings, just the TCP/IP of the host. If, for example, it's a named instance you'll need to include that in your connection string properties.

Comment: Look in the SQL Server ERRORLOG to on startup to confirm the active network configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing that port `1443` in your SQL Configuration Manager's TCP/IP Properties screen shot doesn't match the port `1433` that's in your connection properties. Have you tried fixing the port number in your connection string by specifying `"port": 1443,` in your ormconfig.ts or ormconfig.json file?

Comment: I am using Sql Server image on docker, That actually solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should type
port:'',
below the host with the port number in the ''
and the username of the SQL server you want to connect to in the '' username:'',
and the password of the SQL server user login in the password:'',

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error with this:

```js
type: 'mssql',
host: 'example',
port: 1433,
username: 'example', 
password: 'example',
database: 'DBTest', entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
synchronize: true,
```

**extra line**: `{ trustServerCertificate: true, },`